# UIViewController in Customized UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I know it was trivial but I have messed myself up and spent hours.

I have a UIViewController which is composed of CategoryTableview and ProductsTableView.

The ProductsTableView is creating the customized TableViewCell called ProductTableViewCell.

The ProductTableViewCell has title label, detail label, price label and a customized stepper to control the amount of the products which is subclassing from UIViewController.

The stepper, is composed with two buttons and a textfield.

I think the way I'm implementing the program is more complex than it should be.

And my question is how to detect the value changed by the stepper controller in the parent view controller.

The code is:

```
ProductionViewController.h (parent view controller for listing everything)

@interface ProductionViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITableView* categoryTable;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITableView* productsTable;

@property (nonatomic,strong) CheckOutBar* checkOutBar;

//datasources
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray* menuLists;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray* detailLists;

//datefield
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* startDate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* endDate;
```

the customized cell for products is

```
@interface ProductCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* eqiupmentImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* details;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* prices;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCStepperViewController* stepper;
```

The implementing method of the cell is

```
     @implementation ProductCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    {
        _Title = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _eqiupmentImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        _details = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _details.font = kFONT(12);
        _details.textColor = KColor_Gray;

        _prices  = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _stepper = [[MCStepperViewController alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_stepper.view];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_Title];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_eqiupmentImage];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_details];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_prices];
    } 
        return self;
    }

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [_eqiupmentImage setFrame:CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, kLeftMargin, 80 ,80)];
    [_Title setFrame:CGRectMake(10+CGRectGetMaxX(_eqiupmentImage.frame), kLeftMargin/2, 60, 20)];
    [_details setFrame:CGRectOffset(_Title.frame, 0, 20)];
    [_prices setFrame:CGRectMake(10+CGRectGetMaxX(_eqiupmentImage.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(_eqiupmentImage.frame)-20, 40, 20)];
    [_stepper.view setFrame:CGRectOffset(_prices.frame, 40, 0)];
}
```

The customized stepperview is

```
MCStepperViewController.h  (for controlling the amount of products)
@interface MCStepperViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField  *amountText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton * plusButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton * minusButton;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int max;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int min;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int amount;
```

Thank you

Comment: Explore the concept of Key Value Observing (KVO). You can observe the value of the "amount" variable in the parent view controller. Each time the value is changed, the parent will get Notified, and you can designate a method to be invoked.

Comment: @TheAppMentor Thank you, because the value I want to observe is one property of the stepper controller, and the stepper is the property of the cell. I am not sure I am able to directly observe the value in the main parent controller or I should add a observer in the customized cell?

Comment: @Mix do you want to be notified every time when value change? Or you just want to check current value for sum logic?

Comment: As long as you have the amount delcared as a property (which you have), you should be able to observe changes to its value using KVO. Another option is to post a NSNotification, but I think KVO is meant to handle this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be implementing a protocol in your cells with a method like `- (void)productCell:(ProductCell *)cell didChangeStepperValue:(NSInteger)stepperValue`. Then you make your view controller a delegate of each cell and call this method every time the stepper changes it's value. To separate cells from each other you could assign their `tag` value to your model's corresponding index.

Another way is to use KVO, but you should be careful with subscribing/unsubscribing. And using blocks, of course, is a viable option.

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented a delegate in the cell class, but i cannot call the stepper controller to perform the delegate method because there is no cell property in stepper but the stepper property is in the cell class

Comment: Why not implement another protocol in your stepper class and implement the corresponding method (say, `- (void)stepperController:(MCStepperViewController *)stepperController valueChanged:(NSInteger)value;`) in your cell? Yeah, it's becoming quite complex, but the structure is pretty clear. Plus you can reuse this control elsewhere without any coupling.

Comment: Done! Thank you very much. And make me have better knowledge of delegate.